# Docker Compose shared CPUs

Tags: docker, cpu, docker-compose

In Docker Compose is there a way to create containers with their own CPU? I don't want them to share CPUs I´ve allocated to them.

Suppose I give to Docker access to 3 CPUs: I want each of my three containers to have its own CPU.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Limit the specific CPUs or cores a container can use. A comma-separated list or hyphen-separated range of CPUs a container can use, if you have more than one CPU. The first CPU is numbered 0. A valid value might be 0-3 (to use the first, second, third, and fourth CPU) or 1,3 (to use the second and fourth CPU).

```
docker run --cpuset-cpus="0" [...]
```

In docker-compose:

```
services:
  service:
    cpuset: "0"
```

Comment: What happens if I have to "scale" one of my containers and create new instances? Does the second instance use the CPU 0 or it gets another one?

Comment: As per compose version 3 you can no longer do this without creating a swarm. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2x-to-3x